powershell, .NET tracing without creating .config file
I want to log the SMTP protocol of System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
as System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient does not provide any mean of doing so, I looked for a way to log the underlying System.Net.Sockets requests and found this stackoverflow answer which gives a way of doing so by inserting the following directives in the .config file of the application.
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>      
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>      
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add
      name="TraceFile"
      type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
      initializeData="trace.log"
    />
  </sharedListeners>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
  </switches>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>

unfortunately, as I don't have the opportunity to modify powershell.exe.config, I looked for a way of starting the trace on the fly in my script and found this stackoverflow answer which gives a way,
$id = [Environment]::TickCount
$fileName = "${PSScriptRoot}\Powershell.log.${id}.txt"
$listener1 = [System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener]::New($fileName, "text_listener")
$listener2 = [System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener]::New()
$listener2.Name = "console_listener"

[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::AutoFlush = $true
[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::Listeners.Add($listener1) | out-null
[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::Listeners.Add($listener2) | out-null

# Use reflection to enable and hook up the TraceSource
$logging = [System.Net.Sockets.Socket].Assembly.GetType("System.Net.Logging")
$flags = [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Static
$logging.GetField("s_LoggingEnabled", $flags).SetValue($null, $true)
$webTracing = $logging.GetProperty("Web", $flags)
$webTraceSource = [System.Diagnostics.Tracesource]$webTracing.GetValue($null, $null);
$webTraceSource.Switch.Level = [System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels]::Information
$webTracesource.Listeners.Add($listener1) | out-null
$webTracesource.Listeners.Add($listener2) | out-null

[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::TraceInformation("About to do net stuff")
[System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("ftp://www.google.com") | out-null
[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::TraceInformation("Finished doing net stuff")

#get rid of the listeners
[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::Listeners.Clear()
$webTraceSource.Listeners.Clear()
$listener1.Dispose()
$listener2.Dispose()

but I am not able to adapt it to my needs.
I tried to replace Web by Sockets in
$webTracing = $logging.GetProperty("Web", $flags)

and do some system.net.mail stuff in place of
[System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("ftp://www.google.com") | out-null

but with no success.
can you teach me how to adapt the above example to make it start traces as described in the XML .config?

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient is obsolete and the class's page itself warns against using it for years. Microsoft itself suggests using MailKit or other open source libraries

Target the field that holds the trace source for the Sockets namespace instead:
# ...
$socketsTraceSource = $logging.GetField('s_SocketsTraceSource', [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'Static,NonPublic').GetValue($null)

$socketsTraceSource.Listeners.Add($listener1) |Out-Null
$socketsTraceSource.Listeners.Add($listener2) |Out-Null

